# Cannot access javax.servlet.Filter class file for javax.servlet.Filter not found

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, spring-3, aws-xray, jakarta-migration

I'm working in a project and right now I'm migrating the project to Spring 3.0. So I made some changes in some classes. I can not share the classes because of the job rules but this class about the AwsXrayConfig class. And using filter. But when I try to build project I'm getting this "cannot access javax.servlet.Filter" error. In the class I already updated javax to jakarta but AWSXRayServletFilter still using com.amazon.xray.javax.servlet.AWSXRayServletFilter library. So I'm stuck here. Also I'm not sure about looking the true place? Is that about jakarta or spring or aws libraries I''m not sure. Any ideas? Thx

I already removed import part about AWSXRayServletFilter but it's complaining. I changed javax.servlet.Filter to jakarta.servlet.Filter. Thats it

Comment: Sounds like a Spring lib issue vs an AWS issue.

Comment: @smac2020 thx for the comment. As I understand still there is no update for aws in spring. So just waiting for that

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for bringing this to our attention.

There is an issue with the latest version of Spring since it is using Jakarta instead of javax.

I will add this as a work item for us.

Answer (score 0):

This is fixed in latest upgrade.
You need to import com.amazonaws:aws-xray-recorder-sdk-core:2.14.0
and other related libraries